# Sharing an enumerator across threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, enumerator

I want to call a common enumerator from different threads. When I do the following,

```
enum = (0..1000).to_enum
t1 = Thread.new do
  p enum.next
  sleep(1)
end
t2 = Thread.new do
  p enum.next
  sleep(1)
end
t1.join
t2.join
```

it raises an error:

```
Fiber called across threads.
```

when `enum` is called from `t2` after once being called from `t1`.

- Why is Ruby designed to not allow an enumerator (or fiber) to be called across threads, and
- Is there an alternative way to provide a similar function?

I am guessing that atomicity of an operation on an enumerator/fiber is relevant here, but am not fully sure. If that is the issue, then exclusively-locking the enumerator/fiber while in use shall solve the problem, and I don't know why calling an enumerator/fiber across threads is prohibited in general. If an alternative can be provided by using locking, that would satisfy my need.

Comment: will a Queue satisfy your needs?

Comment: @UriAgassi If you can do it with it, it would.

Comment: @sawa, what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html)

```
queue = Queue.new
(0..1000).map(&queue.method(:push))

t1 = Thread.new do
  while !queue.empty?
    p queue.pop(true)
    sleep(0.1)
  end
end
t2 = Thread.new do
  while !queue.empty?
    p queue.pop(true)
    sleep(0.1)
  end
end
t1.join
t2.join
```

Comment: I want to be able to reuse it. By popping, it will change.

Comment: This replaces the enumerator, not the array/range/whatever... instead of `rewind` - rebuild it

Comment: I am trying to do this same thing in a ROR application, and I need to be able to use an ActiveRecord query (with a large number of results) as an Enumerator. If I map the whole thing to a Queue, I end up using too much ram. (I'm using the find_each method, so that it only queries in batches of 1000. If I map it to a Queue, I will have the whole table sitting in a variable, which is not practical). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32513535/599402).

Comment: @Ephraim - the trick here is to spin up the threads _before_ filling up the queue. This way the threads will consume the results as you are requesting for them - actually working when you are waiting for the DB to bring the next batch.