# FiberError - Fiber called across threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fiber

I'm trying to write a small feature in a Rails app that uses the [random-word gem](https://github.com/pezra/random-word) to generate a random noun, then pluralize it. I've been able to get it working the first time I visit the page in development, but I want the script to run again on each page load. Right now, subsequent page loads (until I bounce the server) give me `FiberError in WelcomeController#randomwords`, `fiber called across threads`. I attempted to solve this myself, but I'm pretty new to programming and don't really understand how Fibers work. I tried using Queue, but couldn't figure out how to get it to work, again because I don't totally understand the class. How would I go about solving this specific problem?

Source: welcome_helper.rb

```
def random
  noun = RandomWord.nouns.next.split('_').sample.pluralize
  if noun.include? "_"
    noun = noun.split("_").join.pluralize
  else
    noun.pluralize!
  end      
  return noun
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem, as you might have found out by now, is that the `random-word` gem is not thread safe. More precisely, `RandomWord.nouns` is a [module-level Enumerator](https://github.com/openlogic/random-word/blob/master/lib/random_word.rb#L50), and [accessing enumerators across threads is not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966515/sharing-an-enumerator-across-threads)

However, e.g. [`Queue`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) is thread safe, so for a thread-safe alternative to this functionality you could take [`nouns.dat` from the random-word gem](https://github.com/openlogic/random-word/blob/master/data/nouns.dat), and randomly shuffle all its words into a `Queue` object when you initialize your application. Now, say this queue can be accessed via `random_words_queue` in the scope of your `random` method. Then you can implement the `random` method as

```rb
def random
  unless random_words_queue.empty?
    noun = random_words_queue.pop
    if noun.include? "_"
      noun = noun.split("_").join.pluralize
    else
      noun.pluralize!
    end      
    return noun
  end
end
```

Note that it currently just returns `nil` if the queue is empty, which you probably don't want. How you want it to behave in this case depends on your requirements:

- If the words being somewhat predictable is not a security concern, and not likely to annoy your users, then I would just push `noun` to the back of the queue right after popping it.
- Otherwise, you should reshuffle the words.

(In any case, returning `nil` is probably not what anybody wants.)