# Thread safe Enumerator in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, lazy-loading, enumerator

### TLDR: Is there a thread-safe version of the Enumerator class in Ruby?

---

#### What I'm trying to do:

I have a method in a Ruby On Rails application that I wanted to run concurrently. The method is supposed to create a zip file containing reports from the site, where each file in the zip is a PDF. The conversion from html to PDF is somewhat slow, thus the desire to multi-thread.

#### How I expected to do it:

I wanted to use 5 threads, so I figured I would have a shared Enumerator between the threads. Each thread would pop a value from the Enumerator, and run do stuff to it. Here's how I was thinking it would work:

```ruby
t = Zip::OutputStream::write_buffer do |z|
  mutex = Mutex.new
  gen = Enumerator.new{ |g|
    Report.all.includes("employee" => ["boss", "client"], "projects" => {"project_owner" => ["project_team"]}).find_each do |report|
      g.yield report
    end
  }
  5.times.map {
    Thread.new do
      begin
        loop do
          mutex.synchronize  do
            @report = gen.next
          end
          title = @report.title + "_" + @report.id.to_s
          title += ".pdf" unless title.end_with?(".pdf")
          pdf = PDFKit.new(render_to_string(:template => partial_url, locals: {array: [@report]},
                                            :layout => false)).to_pdf
          mutex.synchronize  do
            z.put_next_entry(title)
            z.write(pdf)
          end
        end
      rescue StopIteration
        # do nothing
      end
    end
  }.each {|thread| thread.join }
end
```

#### What happened when I tried it:

When I ran the above code, I got the following error:

```
FiberError at /generate_report
fiber called across threads
```

After some searching, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966515/sharing-an-enumerator-across-threads?lq=1), which recommended that I use a Queue instead of an Enumerator, because Queues are thread safe, while Enumerators are not. While this might be reasonable for non-Rails applications, this is impractical for me.

#### Why I can't just use a Queue:

The nice thing about Rails 4 ActiveRecord is that it doesn't load queries until they are iterated over. And, if you use a method like `find_each` to iterate over it, it does it in batches of 1000, so you never have to store an entire table in ram all at once. The results from query I'm using: `Report.all.includes("employee" => ["boss", "client"], "projects" => {"project_owner" => ["project_team"]})` is large. Very large. And I need to be able to load it on the fly, rather than doing something like:

```ruby
gen = Report.all.includes("employee" => ["boss", "client"], "projects" => {"project_owner" => ["project_team"]}).map(&queue.method(:push))
```

Which will load that entire query into ram.

#### Finally the question:

Is there a thread-safe way of doing this:

```ruby
gen = Enumerator.new{ |g|
        Report.all.includes(...).find_each do |report|
          g.yield report
        end
}
```

So that I can pop data from `gen` across multiple threads, without having to load my entire `Report` (and all of the includes) table into ram?

Answer (score 1):

If you start the worker threads before filling up the queue, they will start consuming the queue as you fill it up, and because as a rule of thumb - network is slower than CPU, each batch should be (mostly) consumed by the time the next batch arrives:

```
queue = Queue.new

t1 = Thread.new do
  while !queue.empty?
    p queue.pop(true)
    sleep(0.1)
  end
end
t2 = Thread.new do
  while !queue.empty?
    p queue.pop(true)
    sleep(0.1)
  end
end

(0..1000).map(&queue.method(:push))

t1.join
t2.join
```

If that proves too slow still, you can opt to use [`SizedQueue`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/SizedQueue.html), which will block the `push` if the queue reaches a big enough size:

```
queue = SizedQueue.new(100)

t1 = Thread.new do
  while !queue.empty?
    p "#{queue.pop(true)} - #{queue.size}"
    sleep(0.1)
  end
end
t2 = Thread.new do
  while !queue.empty?
    p queue.pop(true)
    sleep(0.1)
  end
end
(0..300).map(&queue.method(:push))
t1.join
t2.join
```